# Does "adding rainbows" eventually stabilize in $\ge 4$-color Hackenbush?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

*EDIT: now generalized and [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440805/eventual-stabilization-for-repeatedly-adding-multiplayer-games).*

*This is an outgrowth of [an earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4628676/tricolor-columns-only-hackenbush-boards-must-adding-the-rainbow-board-eventua), which itself was motivated by [an MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439208/monoid-associated-to-2-player-hackenbush). An answer to this question is claimed there as well, but the details are insufficient for me at present, so:*

This is a question about "columns-only $p$-color Hackenbush." Formally, for a natural number $p\ge 4$, a ($p$-)**board** is a finite formal sum (or multiset if one prefers) of finite strings from $[p]=\{1,2,...,p\}$. "Colors" (elements of $[p]$) correspond exactly to players. For $i\in[p]$ and a board $B$, a **legal move in $B$ for player $i$** consists of replacing one occurrence of a string $\sigma\in B$ with one occurrence of a string $\tau$ such that $\tau i\preccurlyeq\sigma$. As in the above-linked questions, define the "basic type" of a board $B$ to be the set $bt(B)$ of pairs $(x,A)$ such that $x\in [p]$, $A$ is a nonempty proper subset of $[p]$, and there are strategies $\pi_a$ for $a\in A$ which when followed ensure that the first player to be unable to move will not be in $A$ assuming player $x$ starts and move ordered proceeds in the obvious cyclic order from then on.

Intuitively, a string $\sigma$ occurring in $B$ represents a "stack of edges" labelled according to $\sigma$ from the ground up, and $(x,A)\in bt(B)$ means "team $A$ can avoid losing in $B$ if $x$ goes first."

Now let ${\bf z}_p=\langle 1\rangle+\langle 2\rangle+...+\langle p\rangle$ be the "rainbow" board with $p$ colors. Interestingly, and in contrast with the two-color version, adding ${\bf z}_p$ does *not* generally preserve basic type (see below). Despite this, I'm curious whether adding ${\bf z}$ does *eventually* preserve basic type:

> Fix $p\ge 4$. For a board $B$, is there necessarily a natural number $k$ such that $$bt(B+m{\bf z}_p)=bt(B+n{\bf z}_p)$$ whenever $m,n\ge k$?

Here $aC=C+C+C+...+C$ ($a$ times) for $a\in\mathbb{N}$ and $C$ a board.

To motivate the constraint on $p$, consider the $p=2$ and $p=3$ cases of the same problem. When there are only two players, we're just looking at Red-Blue Hackenbush and "adding ${\bf z}_p$" to a game *never* affects the basic type of a game. When $p=3$ this is no longer the case - consider e.g. $\langle 123\rangle$ vs. $\langle 123\rangle +{\bf z}_3$, with players $1$ and $2$ on the same team and $1$ moving first - but the situation is still pretty simple: adding ${\bf z}_p$ to a game can only make things better for a coalition consisting of all but one player, and that's all the coalitions there are when $p\le 3$. For $p\ge 4$, though, things seem more complicated (e.g. consider $A=\{1,3\}$). On the other hand, I don't yet have an example of a $p$-board $B$ where the "basic type sequence" $$\mathfrak{Z}(B):=\langle bt(B+k{\bf z}_p)\rangle_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$$ ever changes value more than once, so things might wind up being the same as with $p=3$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Since that argument needs more detail, I've decided to keep this question open; you can add your argument here when you get a chance to flesh it out.